# Can't upload document to docushare (error 712)

Tags: upload, docushare

I've got a problem with DocuShare: I can't upload new document to the server; 
When we first got this problem looked over the net and it said it was because there wasn't enough space left on the archiving drive (less then 10%) so we added more space. it worked for a day then the same problem occurred; 
And now, we still have the same problem and we don't know what to do; if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

The client did not restart the server nor services after the memory upgrade; Something they should have done to make the changes happen. Then everything is good now;